# Facebook API: Post likes edge has no total_count field

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

My query on the Facebook graph explorer is ..../175126819173613_796398493713106/likes?fields=total_count

Where the long number is a post id. For some reason, the post/likes edge only has a data field and the above query fails with:

```
   {
      "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: total_count.", 
      "type": "OAuthException", 
      "code": 100
      }
   }
```

The reference says that each like edge should have a total_counts field so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question but,
`175126819173613_796398493713106/likes?summary=1&limit=0`

gives

```
{
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
        "total_count": 2
    }
}
```